# How to make asp.net app run with visual studio server instead of IIS?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis

I have downloaded this blog engine
https://github.com/lelandrichardson/MiniBlog

I cannot run it within Visual Studio because it wants IIS : how to change this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your project doesn't load in Visual Studio (it is greyed out), you need to manually edit the project file (MiniBlog.csproj) in a text editor. You just need to look for the `UseIIS` tag, and change its value to `False`:

```
<UseIIS>False</UseIIS>
```

When you do the above, Visual Studio should be able to load the project. It should now default to the Visual Studio web server.

Once you are able to load the project in Visual Studio, you can choose another web server, if you wish. You just need to right-click on the project in the tree view and then select `Properties`. From there, if you open the `Web` tab, you can choose the legacy Visual Studio Web Development Server, IIS Express (you may need to install this), or the Server version of IIS.

Just a note - I was unable to actually build the project that you linked to. There appear to be missing dlls, but that is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: for missing dll yes it's out of the scope

Answer (score 1):

try to add IIS Express 7.5 for visual studio http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1038

Comment: In fact I have IIS installed. What I want to know is how to just even load the project in Visual Studio.